# Elementor is not starting

Tags: protractor, elementor

I have installed Elementor for protractor e2e testing. as descibed [here](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor). But whenever I start it like this, I get following results.

```
E:\Work\test>elementor https://angularjs.org
Creating protractor configuration file
Starting protractor
Running command: [node C:\Users\Vikash777\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elementor\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js --elementExplorer true --debuggerServerPort 6969 C:\Users\VIKASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\protractor-conf117814-7776-q2aq5m.jdozu84cxr]

E:\Work\test>
```

**UPDATE**

There I have started Selenium server in separate windows

[image]

It does not start Elementor..

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue if you have the port number 6969 on your machine already in use. Can you give it a try by using some other port number or releasing the port 6969 of its current running process(if any)

Comment: I have checked, there is nothing running on port 6969

Comment: Try specifying a different port, just in case.

Comment: I don't know, where and how to specify a different port number?

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to separately start the selenium webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command in cmd. When i have used it last 3 month ago i block the port no 90 and then try it on CMD.

```
E:\Work\test>elementor https://angularjs.org
Creating protractor configuration file
Starting protractor
Running command: [node C:\Users\Vikash777\AppData\ [lunchtime predictions for today][1]\Roaming\npm\node_modules\elementor\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js --elementExplorer true --debuggerServerPort 6969 C:\Users\VIKASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\protractor-conf117814-7776-q2aq5m.jdozu84cxr]

E:\Work\test>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# DO system reboot 
# Start selenium webserver 
# Check Posts not being used.
```

I would do it if it was mine.